# Construction of sentences

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, difference

What is the difference between construction of sentences?

He sat at the table and consumed a pie.
At the table he sat and consumed a pie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In practical terms, there is no difference.

However, it's *possible* to construe a subtle difference.

> 1. He sat at the table and consumed a pie.

This doesn't *necessarily* mean that he consumed a pie at the *exact* time that he sat at the table. In theory, the sentence could also describe him sitting at the table, getting up, and *then* consuming a pie (while standing).

> 2. At the table[,] he sat and consumed a pie.

Since this is an introductory dependent clause followed by an independent clause (as opposed to either two independent clauses or a compound independent clause—depending on how you view it—in in the first sentence), it describes one thing that happened *at the same time as* another thing.

In this case, there is no mistake that the pie was consumed *while* he was sitting at the table.

---

In short, while the pie *might* have been consumed (and probably was) while he sat at the table in the first sentence, it was *definitely* consumed while he sat at the table in the second sentence.

Having said that, most people would assume the same meaning for both sentences.